# sequelize return undefined with a like query %o%

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I can't find any resource out there with this issue. The query is a little more complicated than the one below, so like rewriting the query into a raw is kind of not an option (unless I can't find a solution).

I am trying to run a search query with the query params = 'open' (anything with an 'o' in the beginning) will produce this output. Using MySQL 5.7.

```
return await models.Order.findAll({
  where: {
    order_status: {
      [Op.like]: '%open%',
    },
  },
});


SELECT * FROM 
`orders` AS `Order` WHERE `Order`.`order_status` LIKE 'undefinedpen%';
```

Comment: Using `"sequelize": "^4.37.6"`

Comment: Did you try a different version of sequelize to see if that fixed it?

Comment: I did but going try again, I was working with version `4.30.1`

Comment: Yup, no, no luck

Comment: Fixed, @JakeMiller, added double %% at the beginning something like [Op.like]: '%%open%',

Comment: Sorry I wasn't of much help. You should report that as a bug to sequelize because I couldn't find anything on it and I don't think that's proper behavior. Glad you found a fix.